# @Projection not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I've implemented a little sample project to illustrate the problem I have. It's located here:

```
https://github.com/jvillane/spring-boot-hateoas-rest
```

What i'm trying to do is creating several **@Projection**'s of the same Entity:

```java
@Projection(name = "S", types = User.class)
public interface UserS {
    String getName();
}

@Projection(name = "M", types = User.class)
public interface UserM {
    String getName();
    String getDni();
}

@Projection(name = "L", types = User.class)
public interface UserL {
    String getName();
    String getDni();
    Country getCountry();
}
```

And using them to obtain more or less **Entity** information by calling (with and without quotes):

```java
http://localhost:8080/api/users/1?projection=S
http://localhost:8080/api/users/1?projection=M
http://localhost:8080/api/users/1?projection=L
```

But it doesn't make a difference in the response, it's like it's using the default way to show the Entity info.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the following. Is your Projection definition in the same package (or subpackage) as the corresponding entity.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections

> **How does Spring Data REST finds projection definitions?**
>
> Any `@Projection` interface found in the same package as your entity
>   definitions (or one of it’s sub-packages) is registered.
>
> You can manually register via
>   `RepositoryRestConfiguration.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(…)`.
>
> In either situation, the interface with your projection MUST have the
>   `@Projection` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

your class "entities", and your "interface" of Projection corresponding to your entitie must be in some package.
for your case : entitie class UserS, and interface(Projection) USerS , must be in some package